# Android Studio: Test passes in debug mode but fails while using the run option

Tags: android, android-studio, android-instrumentation

I have a simple test case where I'm trying to validate if a specific view is being loaded upon clicking on another view

```
public class SimpleActivityTest extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<SimpleActivity> {

private SimpleActivity mActivity;

public SimpleActivityTest() {
    super(SimpleActivity.class);
}

@Override
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    super.setUp();
    mActivity = getActivity();
}

@SmallTest
public void testBrushToolbar() {
    View rootView = mActivity.getWindow().getDecorView();
    View brush = mActivity.findViewById(R.id.brush1);

    TouchUtils.clickView(this, brush);

    ViewAsserts.assertOnScreen(rootView, mActivity.findViewById(R.id.container));
    }
}
```

The above test fails when I use the **Run** option in Android Studio. Mainly because the *TouchUtils.clickView()* seems to not do anything at all and the new view is never loaded.

However, the same test passes when I use the **Debug** option even without setting any breakpoints!

I tried adding a *Thread.sleep()* and then running the test but even that didn't help. Any idea as to why this might be happening?

PS: I'm running on Android Studio 1.3.1

*Update:* The test fails even when I run from the command line using

```
$ gradle installDebug installDebugAndroidTest && adb shell am instrument -w -e class com.mypackage.test.SimpleActivityTest#testBrushToolbar com.mypackage.test/android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner
```